# Javascript nested array to single array without using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JSON array like this:

```
var items = [
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'},...]  ,
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'},...]  ,
]
```

From that I need an array like this:

```
var newArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'test' }, { id: 2, name: 'test'}, { id: 3, name: 'test'}, ...
]
```

Now I am using a `for` loop on `items` array and storing into `newArray` but is there any other method without using loops?

Comment: What is the third element in newArray ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai its same as `{id:1,name:'test'}`

Comment: I think i'm not the only who can't understand your question. Please provide more details.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) is by definition a string, you have an array, which is not a JSON.

Comment: Why don't you wish to use a loop, whatever you're going to do it'll involve some sort of a loop.

Comment: @Tschallacka: Depends on if you consider `[].concat.apply([], arrays);` to be a loop. Sure, behind the scenes...

Answer (score 1):

**Demo 1:** [**`concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [**`.apply()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

---

**Demo 2:** [**`reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and `concat()`

---

**Demo 3:** [**`...` Spread Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and `concat()`

---

### Demo 1

```js
var items = [
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}]  ,
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}]  ,
]

var flattened = [].concat.apply([], items);

console.log(flattened);
```

### Demo 2

```js
var items = [
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}],
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}]
];

var flattened = items.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr);
});

console.log(flattened);
```

### Demo 3

```js
var items = [
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}],
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}] 
];

var flattened = [].concat(...items);

console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: symple always love it

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates like this one. Close-vote them instead.

Answer (score 1):

I love functional and new prototpes of array  so here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qyopbwwq/)

```
var items = [
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}]  ,
   [{id:1,name:'test'},{id:2,name:'test'}] 
]
var ll = items.reduce(function(prev, current){return prev.concat(current)})
console.log(ll)
```